# unable to add on to float

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, escaping

I have the following code

`mFme.Profile.VideoOutput_DataRate = Configs.VideoBitRate;`

Configs.VideoBitRate is a public float that is returned from an XML file.

What I would like to be able to do is

mFme.Profile.VideoOutput_DataRate = Configs.VideoBitRate + "\;" + Configs.VideoBitRate2;

My problem is : I cannot seem to find a proper way to set the variable like that. It is important that I have semicolon between the two bitrates. I.E 200;650

Does anyone know the proper way to accomplish this? I am very familiar with PHP, but not c#.net. What I thought would be a simple task.. is anything but at the moment.

Comment: what is the datatype of mFme.Profile.VideoOutput_DataRate?

Comment: What do you mean set the variable like that? ; does not require an escape character. Just do `mFme.Profile.VideoOutput_DataRate = Configs.VideoBitRate + ";" + Configs.VideoBitRate2;`

If this doesn't solve your problem, what is the value you are getting for your _DataRate after assignment?

Answer (score 1):

What your attempting to do is simply not possible.  A `float` value in .Net can't have an embedded semi-colon, it's just not a part of the number specification.  The intrinsic which can represent the pattern you're attempting is a `string` value.

```
string rate = Configs.VideoBitRate + ";" + Configs.VideoBitRate2;
```

Comment: I tried adding the string you provided, and changing the right side of the = sign in my code to rate, but am still receiving you cannot convert float to string. I did not write the application, I am only in charge of repairing it, so I am a bit stuck.

Comment: @RobertDickey what is the type of VideoBitRate, VideoBitRate2 and VideoOutput_Daterate?

Comment: Both are floats. Not sure why

Comment: @RobertDickey both or all 3?

Comment: Oops, all three are floats. The whole point behind this, is that FMLE CMD creates a video file for each DataRate reclared in this format 200;300;400 but with the way the app is created with Floats, it seems I can only pass the one.

Comment: @RobertDickey that would appear to be the case.  There is no way to pass `;` as a part of a `float` value. It sounds like you will need another parameter

Answer (score 0):

if `mFme.Profile.VideoOutput_DataRate` is of type **string** then you can do this, no need of escape character.

```
mFme.Profile.VideoOutput_DataRate = Configs.VideoBitRate + ";" + Configs.VideoBitRate2;
```

if **mFme.Profile.VideoOutput_DataRate** is of type **float** then you cannot do this.